# Changing Apache document root on AWS EC2 does not work

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services

I have a PHP file in this directory : `/home/ec2-user/folder/file.php` and I setup the LAMP server.

What I tried:

A. Changing the document root inside the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

I changed the DocumentRoot and the Directory and I change the Override to All. Here is the changes I made:

```
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user/folder"

#<Directory "/var/www/html">
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/folder">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

But If I call `<publicDNS>/file.php` I get the requested URL was not found on the server.

B. Create a `serveExternal.php` file inside the `/var/www/html` folder.

Content is:

```
 $fileName = $_GET['filename'];
 echo $fileName;   // shown correctly
 $cwd = getcwd(); // get the current working directory
 echo $cwd ; // prints the /var/www/html
 chdir ("/home/ec2-user/folder/"); // Change directory to /home/bitnami/folder/
 require_once($fileName); // include the required file
 chdir ($cwd); // Change the directory to its original location
```

But then my PHP file is never called.

Any solutions?

Comment: `/home/bitnami/folder/file.php` !== `/home/ec2-user/folder`

Comment: @MarkBaker typo fixed, I am talking about the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the DocumentRoot to /home/bitnami/folder your files are in this folder and you are setting document root to different user's directory, so you are not able to access those files.

Comment: sorry it was a typo. Directories are the same , typo fixed. please read again :)

Comment: Did you restart/reload the apache server after the change?

Comment: yes I did. Basically I exited my AWS and when logged in again I ran sudo service httpd start.Do I need to do something else?

Comment: restarting the apache did the trick, now having a different error but will post a new question.