# Change document root on RStudio_AMI

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rstudio, amazon-ami

It is on an amazon server so I checked the following post:
[Changing Apache document root on AWS EC2 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857982/changing-apache-document-root-on-aws-ec2-does-not-work)
and 
[How to edit httpd.conf file in AMAZON EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112424/how-to-edit-httpd-conf-file-in-amazon-ec2)
or in general: [How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)
Well the information provided did help me so far.
The only file I could find in the etc/apache2 folder is the following:
[image]

Edit: The content of the config file is:
"Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/

Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

"

I asked two month ago on his site: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/, but didnt get an answer.

My question: How can i change the document root on an RStudio AMI server, so that I can change the directory of the rstudio login page away from the root directory to - say - domain.com/login and have a landing page + other folders on the root (domain.com).

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
After the answer from Frédéric Henri and edit:

Here is the content of my rstudio.conf file.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
  proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_read_timeout 20d;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/rstudio-access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/rstudio-error.log;
}
```

Assuming i have the index.html file in the directory /home/idx/index.html, how would i change the file then.
The following didnt work for me:

```
  proxy_pass http://localhost/home/idx;
  proxy_redirect http://localhost/home/idx/ $scheme://$host/;
```

Or:

```
  proxy_pass /home/idx;
  proxy_redirect /home/idx/ $scheme://$host/;
```

and where would i configure to redirect my rstudio login to.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the contents of listed conf file ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made an edit in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and looking at the right place if you were using apache2/httpd web server; but in the case of the RStudio AMI it uses [nginx web server](https://nginx.org/en/) so all configuration are stored in `/etc/nginx`

*You can review [Configure nginx with multiple locations with different root folders on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570321/configure-nginx-with-multiple-locations-with-different-root-folders-on-subdomain) to see how you can work with the conf file*

In your current configuration, it is defined mainly 3 locations:

- `http://<web_server_ip>/`

The conf file used for this case is `/etc/nginx/RStudioAMI/rstudio.conf` It processes all request and forward to http://localhost:8787 where rstudio is running.

- `http://<web_server_ip>/julia`

The conf file used for this case is `/etc/nginx/RStudioAMI/julia.conf` It processes all request and forward to http://localhost:8000 where julia is running.

- `http://<web_server_ip>/shiny`

The conf file used for this case is `/etc/nginx/RStudioAMI/shiny.conf` It processes all request and forward to http://localhost:3838 where shiny is running.

For example you could have the main location (which is simply `/` pointing to a specific folder) and changed the rstudio.conf to handle `http://<web_server_ip>/rstudio`

EDIT

*where would i configure to redirect my rstudio login to*

If you want the rstudio login page to be accessible from `http://<server>/rtudio` (for example) you would need to change in the `/etc/nginx/RStudioAMI/rstudio.conf``

```
location /rstudio/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8787/;
  proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_read_timeout 20d;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/rstudio-access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/rstudio-error.log;
}
```

If you want to point the main `http://<server>/index.html` pointing to `/home/idx/index.html` you need to change in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/RStudioAMI.conf` and have a main location defined pointing to your root element

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  index index.html;

  location = / {
      root /var/www/html;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/RStudioAMI/*.conf;
}
```

Note: Anytime you make a change to a nginx conf file, you need to restart nginx.
with: `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer, it is already of great help, but i couldnt finish it yet. Could you take another look?

Comment: Sry, it takes me a while. I try to figure out as much as I can on my own. The solution above didnt work for me yet, but i found another article which was published a few days ago: https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-server-series-part-2-running-shiny-on-multiple-ports/, which also points in that direction.

Comment: would it be possible for you to take another look?